# Spring form validation error

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

my spring mvc application has a form input box when i validate input using v form validatio it throw errors on server...
And i have set error message on messages.properties file also.

**error**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: validation failed for classes [com.company.product.domain.Rating] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
```

**Rating Domain**

```
  @Entity
    @Table(name = "rating")
    public class Rating {
        int id;
        @NotEmpty
        String name;
        Date createdDate;
        boolean isDelete;

        getter,setter
    }
```

in  my domain i set  validation for one field-"name"

**controller**

@RequestMapping(value = "/add-rating")

```
public String addRating(@ModelAttribute(value = "rating") Rating rating,BindingResult result) {
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "/secure/admin/rating";
    }
    java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
    Date sqlDate = new Date(utilDate.getTime());
    rating.setCreatedDate(sqlDate);
    ratingService.saveRating(rating);
    return "redirect:/rating";
}
```

Why is not validating form error??

Comment: so what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not instructed Spring to run the validation process.
In order to do that you need to add `@Valid`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add-rating")
public String addRating(@Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "rating") Rating rating,BindingResult result) {
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "/secure/admin/rating";
    }
    java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
    Date sqlDate = new Date(utilDate.getTime());
    rating.setCreatedDate(sqlDate);
    ratingService.saveRating(rating);
    return "redirect:/rating";
}
```

Check out [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/) tutorial for more information.